# Как правильно работать с объектом класса в другом классе?C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

```
#include <iostream>
class Pri {
public:
    Pri(int data, int time) { 
        this->data = data;
        this->time = time;
    }
    void getter() const { std::cout << data << " : " << time<< " "; };
private:
    int data,time;
};

class Event {
public:
    Event(Pri & a, std::string s) {    //коструктор в который передан объект
        this->obj = &a;
        this->eve = s; };

    void getter2() {
        std::cout << obj << " : " << eve ; //  вывод адреса указателя
    };
private:
    std::string eve;
    Pri* obj;       //хранение объекта другого класса
};

int main() {
    Pri s1(12, 21);         // создание и инициализация  объекта
    s1.getter();            //вывод полей на экран
    std::cout <<&s1<< std::endl;           //проверка адреса объекта
    Event g(s1, "asdfa");  // создание и инициализация  объекта
    g.getter2();           //вывод полей на экран
    return 0;
}
```

Итак. Передача объекта класса Pri в класс Event происходит успешно. В ф-ии getter2 выводится правильный адрес переданного объекта s1. При попытке разыменования (*obj) естесно происходит ошибка. Но и при вызове"(obj.getter()" происходит ошибка. Вопрос как правильно работать с объектом класса внутри другого? Как достучаться до его родных геттеров и при инициализации объекта "g" вывести на экран"12,21 : asdfa "?

Comment: *При попытке разыменования (*obj) естесно происходит ошибка. Но и при вызове"(obj.getter()" происходит ошибка.* - и где все это происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас Ошибка в обращении к указателю.
Для обращения к указателю необходимо использовать оператор ->

```
#include <iostream>


class Pri {
public:
    Pri(int data, int time) : data(data), time(time) {}

    void getter() const
    {
        std::cout << data << " : " << time<< " " << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int data;
    int time;
};


class Event {
public:
    Event(Pri& a, std::string s) : obj(&a), eve(s) {}    //коструктор в который передан объект

    void getter2()
    {
        obj->getter();
        std::cout << eve << std::endl; //  вывод адреса указателя
    };

private:
    std::string eve;
    Pri* obj;       //хранение объекта другого класса
};


int main()
{
    Pri s1(12, 21);         // создание и инициализация  объекта
    s1.getter();            //вывод полей на экран
    Event g(s1, "asdfa");  // создание и инициализация  объекта
    g.getter2();           //вывод полей на экран
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все доперло! Спасибо @VTT за наводящий вопрос)) Моя ошибка в синтаксисе std::cout  << obj.getter() <<" : " << eve ;
Нужно же просто вызвать геттер, а затем написать cout:
obj->getter();
std::cout  << " : " << eve ;
Тогда все ок